# i18n with chart.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I render the chart.js chart, with this way.

```
  def show_line_chart(chart_data)    
    line_chart chart_data, {animation: false,    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false, bezierCurve: false}
  end
```

It will give me the html like that, How could I add the USD or JPY for the price number dynamically.

```
<figure class="chart"><canvas id="chart-0" width="2362" height="812" style="width: 1181px; height: 406px;"></canvas></figure>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiBgi.png]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the code in the question is JavaScript or something else that compiles into JavaScript.

With that caveat, you can set the formatting using the `multiTooltipTemplate` option that you pass in as an option. The JavaScript code would look like

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myCurrencySymbol = 'USD'
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    animation: false, responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false, bezierCurve: false,
    multiTooltipTemplate: function (d) {
        return d.value + ' ' + myCurrencySymbol;
    }
});
```

The point being that you can pass in a function to `multiTooltipTemplate` (and not just interpolated strings)

I've hardcoded `myCurrencySymbol` here, but you should be getting that from your locale service / library or setting it based on the locale. Note that this is assuming that you are actually doing the conversion on the server side (because 100 USD <> 100 JPY obviously)

---

That said, looks like your `multiTooltipTemplate` is already overridden from the default. So you might want to hunt it down (Ctrl + F) and copy over what you need from the template.

The dataset name is available as d.datasetLabel (just like d.value is used currently)